# Fullcalendar scroll from external list

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-draggable

I'm trying to get a Fullcalendar view to scroll when dragging an event to it from an external list.

First the calendar didn't scroll at all, but I solved that by setting `appendTo` to something more appropriate than `body`.

```
appendTo: ".fc-agenda-slots tbody"
```

It kind of works right now as the view is scrolling properly, but the target area in the calendar in which the event will 'land in' doesn't follow the mouse/event. If I scroll down 1 page and drop the event, the event will be dropped ~1 page up, in an area that isn't currently visible. If I scroll back up I can find the target area again, but I can visually confirm that it's out of sync with the event I'm dragging.

Have anyone encountered a similar problem or have some insight into fullcalendar?